# Studying machine learning paper for a non-math major

Tags: machine-learning, research

I have a question and I am not sure if anyone have an answer for it but I appreciate any insights, thoughts, or experiences you might have.
I am a CS major and I have passed

- Calculus I, II , III
- Probability and statistic for engineering
- Applied combinatorics
- Linear algebra
- Numerical linear algebra
- Differential equations
- Algorithm analysis and design
- Machine learning

I may not proficient in all these subjects(since I passed some of them 10 years ago) but I know where to look for the answers when I encounter a simple problem that is related to one of these subjects.

I have done proof problem for important theorem in those classes. But I am not convenient in reading CS paper that has a lot of mathematical proof and  of course I don't know how to write such papers. As an example when I read [this paper](http://ai.stanford.edu/~ang/papers/nips01-spectral.pdf) I could understand up to the end of section 2.  In section 3 when it starts having assumptions, theorem and proof, I get frustrated and I cannot understand the paper well. Probably If I spend 4 days, I will get it. 
I have encountered a lot of such papers are in CS or IE( for example [this paper](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1527&context=compsci&sei-redir=1&referer=https%3A%2F%2Fscholar.google.com%2Fscholar%3Fhl%3Den%26q%3DCarlos%2BGuestrin%26btnG%3D%26as_sdt%3D1%252C39%26as_sdtp%3D#search=%22Carlos%20Guestrin%22)). I expected the courses I passed(listed above), help me to understand them in a reasonable amount time.

I want to start doing research in machine learning but I don't know I am ready to even choose a topic. My question is I struggled in reading such papers because :

1- I have not read enough related paper. It is natural to spend great amount of time for a non-math major. So I should spend days for the first few papers and I can improve later.

2- The courses I listed are not enough and I need to study more for having the skill to read and write such papers.  If that is the case do you have any suggestions what class should I take to help me to improve?

3- I should find an advisor that published such papers,  taking her/his classes and If I passed the class, hopefully I will be ready to understand them.

What is the best strategy to improve? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt that anyone here can provide a "best strategy" - to do so calls for more information about you and your program than you can provide here. If you are at a school perhaps you can find a (potential) advisor in the field. When you meet he or she may be able to suggest papers to start with that match your level of preparation, and may be able to help you over hard parts on occasion. Taking a course with that person would indeed be a good idea.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks for your insight. I am in graduated program in CS right now. Initially, I thought I can read papers by myself before choosing an advisor, but I found I cannot understand them in reasonable amount of time. So I was not sure if it is normal or maybe I need to switch area of interest.

Comment: "Probably If I spend 4 days, I will get it." That doesn't sound so bad, to be honest. I would assume those papers are usually written for people who are into the specific subject at hand. The courses you list are very generic, while papers like the first one you linked are very specific (haven't looked at the other one, but I'd say that's common for most papers in current research). You will probably have to read the literature referenced in the paper and maybe a couple of other papers to get into the subject.

Comment: @polynomial_donut Thanks for your insight. I assumed people may have much easier time reading these papers than me. Most of the researches I have done are  applied research and I could not imagine where non-math majors learn to write paper full of theorems and proofs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone through any machine learning textbooks?

Books like K.P. Murphy's Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective have reasonably up to date coverage of a lot of topics, and are a good place to start with getting up to the basics of the field (for example, the paper you link on spectral clustering has been textbook / [tutorial](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~aarti/Class/10701/readings/Luxburg06_TR.pdf) material for a while).

Larry Wasserman's All of statistics is a useful supplement.

After that, reading papers is somewhat about maturity and takes practice -- you can get the ideas of the papers faster if you've seen more of them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Recently, I have finished Numerical Linear Algebra by Trefethen, and now I started reading Pattern recognition and Machine Learning by Christopher Bishop.  It is helping me to solve some problems but reading it is not that easy for me(spend days for one chapter). In addition, I still feel this wont be enough for doing research. Sometime I think if I really want to read and write papers that has theory and formal proof I need a degree in math. Though I don't think all of such authors have a degree in math. Also thanks for the books and links I will look at them.

Comment: The converse of this is that you get more people to like you by writing expositional works and textbooks than you do by doing new research and writing papers, or at least that's what I've heard

Comment: Theres around a semester's worth (maybe more) of material for a graduate course in Bishop's PRML. It's prerequisite for doing research in an area to know the basics of the area, which Murphy or PRML or similar cover.

Comment: @Tiffany I don't think a Math major necessarily teaches how to write proofs, so don't get hung up on not having majored in it...